# Python pip2 fails - ImportError: No module named moves

Tags: python, pip

I can't run pip2, which is installed from its Arch Linux package:

```
$ pip2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip2", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern.six.moves import urllib, map, filter
ImportError: No module named moves
```

I reinstalled python2-pip2 and python2-setuptools with no results. This has been a problem for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't understand the issue, it is possible to reset it by removing locally (`--user`) installed packages:

Move all packages installed as the user:

```
mv ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages ~/site-packages-bak
```

or try to pinpoint the problematic files. In my case, for some reason I had a python file and its `pyc` file lying around the `site-packages` directory and just moving them solved my issue:

```
mv ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py ~/six.py-bak
mv ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.pyc ~/six.pyc-bak
```